# How do you find all records with a field array count greater than a certain amount in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I basically have a `User` object and defined inside of it is an array `field` `phone_numbers`.  I want to get all of the user objects in my database that have a `phone_numbers` count greater than `1`.
Is there a resource to learn about queries like this?  I couldn't find anything useful online as most of the results were for more simply queries.

Code:

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :phone_numbers, type: Array
end
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Location.where("this.phone_numbers.count < 1").count
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This query search if exists any object in the `phone_numbers[0]` field

```
Location.where(:"phone_numbers.0".exists => true).count
```

This query solve your problem getting the count of phone numbers greater than 1; if exist the field `phone_numbers[0]` it means at least phone number in the array

Answer (score 1):

Will not be able to check this information by query...create a field in your document which will keep the count of `phone_numbers` array, update the value you save the document everytime like this

```
class Location
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name
   field :phone_numbers, type: Array
   field :phone_number_count, type: Integer

   after_save do |location|
      if location.phone_numbers.blank?
         location.phone_number_count = 0
      else
         location.phone_number_count = location.phone_numbers.size 
      end
      location.save
   end
end
```

and you can then run the query

```
Location.where(:phone_number_count.gt => 1).enteries
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this idea after searching without success for a solution avoiding aggregations:

```
array_sizes_to_avoid = (0..1).map do |avoid_count| 
  { phone_numbers: { '$size' => avoid_count } }
end
User.not(User.any_of(array_sizes_to_avoid))
```

It's a bit clunky, but it works.

Comment: miguel savignano's answer is shorter and will work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Location.where(:phone_numbers.gte => '1').count
```